# CellSignalStrength class in Android and obtaining the strength level as an INT

Tags: java, android

I am trying to obtain the cell signal strength and just display it in a text view. I believe CellSignalStrength.getLevel() returns an INT but when I run this code I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.telephony.CellSignalStrength.getLevel()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.telephony.CellSignalStrength.getLevel()' on a null object reference
            at com.steel.signaltest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.CellSignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.telephony.CellSignalStrength;





public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public CellSignalStrength signal;
    public int strength;
    public TextView view;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        strength = signal.getLevel();

        view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
        view.setText(strength);





    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CellSignalStrength` is null.

Here is an example:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
// for example value of first element
CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```

Comment: Is this just for GSM strength though?

Comment: Major Android phones like Samsung does not support this command.